# Frames are not cleared after making WebGLRenderer alpha: true to have transparent background in Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

[image: Example of error]

Code for settings, if i remove the alpha: true, **the problem goes**.

```
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { alpha: true } );

  renderer.setSize(width, height);

  camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera(-width / 2, width / 2, height / 2, -height / 2, 1, 1000);

  camera.position.z = 500;
```

Comment: Can you try with `WebGLRenderer.autoClear = true` ? What happens?

Comment: @adelriosantiago I tried it before, same result...

Comment: The final rendering step was 

$('#canvas')[0].getContext('2d').drawImage(renderer.domElement, 0, 0);

Which is the jQuery drawImage function, by removing it and replacing it with 

$('#canvas').append(renderer.domElement);

The error was gone, no idea why.